# Sorting pandas dataframe based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
   Level Parent   Type
0     A1   None   Saga
1     B4     A2   Epic
2      C     B1  Story
3      C     B1  Story
4     B3     A2   Epic
5      C     B2  Story
6      C     B2  Story
7      C     B1  Story
8      C     B2  Story
9     A2   None   Saga
10    B1     A1   Epic
11     C     B2  Story
12     C     B2  Story
13     C     B3  Story
14    B2     A1   Epic
15     C     B4  Story
16     C     B4  Story
17     C     B4  Story
```

I want to sort the dataframe.

Level is the highest category by which to sort.

If there are other rows which have the same content in the parent line as other level lines, this line should appear directly below.

Lower levels have priority over the middle ones, so something like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can solve this= I already tried it with sort_values, but this does not work

Comment: need text or code of input to solve, not image

Comment: It's probably a graph problem so you can use `networkx`

Comment: the dataframe is included now

Comment: What if `A1` was named `Z1`? Would it change the order? i.e. do you base order on hierarchy or lexicographic order? Please provide the **complete** expected output

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph problem, [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) can be very helpful. The idea is to create your own rank of edges (Parent, Level) before sort your dataframe:

```
# pip install networkx
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

# Create the graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Parent', target='Level', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
root = np.nan  # <- assuming you have only one root
leaves = [node for node, degree in G.out_degree() if degree == 0]

# Find all paths
paths = []
for leaf in leaves:
    for path in nx.all_simple_edge_paths(G, root, leaf):
        paths.append(pd.DataFrame(path, columns=['Parent', 'Level']))

# Define the rank of each edge
rank = pd.concat(paths).drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True).reset_index(names='Rank')

# Broadcast the rank to all rows
df = df.merge(rank, on=['Level', 'Parent']).sort_values('Rank')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Level Parent   Type  Rank
0     A1    NaN   Saga     0
12    B1     A1   Epic     1
2      C     B1  Story     2
3      C     B1  Story     2
4      C     B1  Story     2
14    B2     A1   Epic     3
10     C     B2  Story     4
9      C     B2  Story     4
8      C     B2  Story     4
7      C     B2  Story     4
6      C     B2  Story     4
11    A2    NaN   Saga     5
1     B4     A2   Epic     6
15     C     B4  Story     7
16     C     B4  Story     7
17     C     B4  Story     7
5     B3     A2   Epic     8
13     C     B3  Story     9
```

Intermediate steps:

```
>>> rank
   Rank Parent Level
0     0    NaN    A1
1     1     A1    B1
2     2     B1     C
3     3     A1    B2
4     4     B2     C
5     5    NaN    A2
6     6     A2    B4
7     7     B4     C
8     8     A2    B3
9     9     B3     C
```